# python - confusion how the "as" keyword works in an except statement

Tags: python, oop

I have been trying to understand in general how the "as" keyword in python works so far and have learnt 3 cases for it

Case 1: `import foo as bar`

Case 2: `with foo() as bar:`

Case 3: `except Exception as e:`

I understand how the first 2 cases work, case 1 works assigning a package name to a different name, case 2 works using `__entry__` and `__exit__` methods within a class (say for ensuring resources close), where `__entry__` returns the class `bar` is being assigned to.

However, case 3 seems different, I was looking through the docs which didn't seem to help and couldn't find much of an explanation anywhere. In this case `Exception.args` works differently to `e.args` and I have been trying to work out how this works behind the scenes, i.e. whatever methods may be called, or why it behaves differently

Comment: `Exception` is the exception *class*, and `e` is the exception *object*.

Comment: That `as e` basically assigns the name `e` to the instance of the exception that has been caught, so that you can refer to it (e.g. for logging) within the `except` block.

Comment: See https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-try-statement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the except statement to associate a name to the exception being passed, `as` keyword is used.

Using `as` is the only way to assign the exception to a local in Python 3.x. But it is not required.

In Python 2.6+, we had 2 options `,` and `as`. since `,` is ambiguous in case of multicatch, which allows you to catch multiple exceptions in one except block. `as` is the preferred option.

In Python 2.5 and earlier, we use the `,`for association, since `as` isn't supported.

Answer (score 2):

The phrase `except A as b:` states that in the above `try` clause all exceptions of class `A` (or a subclass thereof) are to be caught.  The actually caught exception will be visible in the variable `b` then.

```
try:
  raise KeyError('example')
except LookupError as problem:
  print("I caught %r as problem." % problem)
```

This will print

```
I caught KeyError('example',) as problem.
```

Comment: Ahh I see, this makes a bit more sense, so the b in this case just catches an object of that class, and you can't go printing LookupError on its own un-initialized in this case if I understand correctly

Comment: @NightShade Yes.  `LookupError` in my example is a _class_ object while `problem` is an _instance_ object.  The first is the type, the second a value of this type.  (Kind of.)

Answer (score 0):

Try running this, which should make it clear.

```
try:
    zero = 0
    b = 1.0 / zero
except ArithmeticError as e:
    print( "Runtime error: ", e)
```

`ArithmeticError` is a Python exception class to be caught. e is an instance of that class, in this case the subclass `ZeroDivisionError`.

Answer (score 0):

Calling `e.args` means that you can access the attributes of the exception object. But it won't catch `BaseException` `SystemExit` `KeyboardInterrupt` and `GeneratorExit`

```
try:
    i = 1/0
    print(i)
except Exception as e:
    print (e.args)
```

This will print:

```
('division by zero')
```

More ever If we rasie `BaseException` error

```
try:
    raise BaseException()
except Exception as e:
    print (e.args)
```

The output will be like this

```
runfile('W:/Summerizer/except.py', wdir='W:/Summerizer')
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-3-11e8f07e28c7>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('W:/Summerizer/except.py', wdir='W:/Summerizer')

  File "C:\Users\adodhiwala\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\py35\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 668, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\Users\adodhiwala\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\py35\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 108, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "W:/Summerizer/except.py", line 10, in <module>
    raise BaseException()

BaseException
```

Here `as` is used to access more functions(args,message etc) so you can understand error more efficiently.